In batch (`.bat`), how do I set a variable to print multiple newlines?
From this other SO post, learned that
SET n=^&echo(

echo First line%n%%n%Second line

prints
First line

Second line


How do I define nn to print 2 new lines? The following didn't work
SET n=^&echo(
SET nn=%n%%n%

echo First line%nn%Second line

It just prints
First lineSecond line


Each of the following works:

SET nn=^&echo(^&echo(
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION SET nn=!n!!n!

but I'm wondering why SET nn=%n%%n% doesn't work.

Is this what you are trying to do? Set "n=&Echo(", Set "nn=%n%%n%%n%", Echo FirstLine%nn%SecondLine.

Why wouldn't you just keep repeating %n%?

First. The explanation why SET nn=%n%%n% doesn't work.
It's because SET n=^&echo( does not define a new line, it's more like a simple macro with many drawbacks.
The expansion works like
SET nn=%n%%n%
Expands in the percent expansion phase to:
SET nn=&echo(&echo(

But in Phase2 the & are detected as special characters and split the line to three commands
set nn=
echo(
echo(

Therefore, the resulting nn variable is empty (undefined).
As said, it's a bad definition at all.
Much better is a real newline
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set n=^
%=this creates an empty line, do not remove=%
)

set nn=!n!!n!

echo Line1!nn!Line2


Thanks. I'm new to .bat. Is %=this creates an empty line, do not remove=% an inline comment? Can it be omitted?

%=this creates an empty line, do not remove=%
)``` didn't work for me

Did you EnableDelayedExpansion @joseville?

@joseville - The comment clearly states to not remove that line.

@joseville It's an inline comment, it could be omitted, but then there has to be an empty line and eventually someone will remove the empty line.

first
SET n=^&echo(^&echo(^&echo(
then
echo First line%n%Second line
output:
First line


Second line


If this is what you are trying to print:
FirstLine


SecondLine

That can be done using:
Set "n=&Echo("
Echo FirstLine%n%%n%%n%SecondLine

Any other way just seems like it adds unnecessary difficulty.

However, if you really must have a variable containing multiple instances of another variable, you could still achieve your goal like this:
Set "n=&Echo("
Set "nn=%n%%n%%n%"
Echo FirstLine%nn%SecondLine

As you can see there is no need to define variables with carets, or to have to enable delayed variable expansion.

Technically however, whilst my previous examples may provide the expected output, %n%%n%%n% seems to show three newlines, which could make it feasible only when another line is to follow it.
My advice therefore, is to define it correctly, then use an explicit Echo command for each of the other lines.
Set "n=&Echo("
Set "nn=%n%%n%"
Echo FirstLine%nn%& Echo SecondLine

It also makes more sense for nn to contain just two newlines.
